# Running from Netbeans enviroment Prints text correctly. Running the same JAR directly does not

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, printing

I am seeing the most unusually dilema.

I have a swing based application. I am printing my jpanel via this code.

**Button Code**

```
private void printDashButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
    try {
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 1 && SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt)) {
            PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            pjob.setJobName("Print ROP Dash");

            PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            attr_set.add(Fidelity.FIDELITY_TRUE);
            attr_set.add(PrintQuality.HIGH);
            attr_set.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
            attr_set.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);

            float width = (float) MediaSize.NA.LETTER.getX(MediaSize.INCH);
            float height = (float) MediaSize.NA.LETTER.getY(MediaSize.INCH);
            attr_set.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0.25f, 0.25f, width - 0.5f, height - 0.5f, MediaPrintableArea.INCH));

            //get the formatter
            PageFormat pf2 = pjob.pageDialog(attr_set);

            //If user does not hit cancel then print.
            if (pf2 != null && pjob.printDialog() == true) {
                //Set print component
                pjob.setPrintable(new Prints(), pf2);

                //print the dash
                pjob.print();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Print Code**

```
//handle the printing
private class Prints implements Printable {
    //convert panel to image

    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
        if (pageIndex > 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        // get the bounds of the component
        Dimension dim = dashHolderPanel.getSize();
        double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
        double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

        // get the bounds of the printable area
        double pHeight = pageFormat.getImageableHeight();
        double pWidth = pageFormat.getImageableWidth();

        double pXStart = pageFormat.getImageableX();
        double pYStart = pageFormat.getImageableY();

        double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
        double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        //g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
        //g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
        g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);
        dashHolderPanel.print(g2);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

If i run the Application from within Netbeans then the Print results in this. Notice the Text Spacing is nice and compact. This is desired.

[image: Narrow Text Spacing when run from Netbeans]

If i run the SAME jar file by simply double clicking it from the explorer window then the Print looks like this. Notice the spacing of text/letters is much wider.

[image: Wide Text Spacing for the same JAR]

Any idea what is happening to cause this difference? Does Netbeans have some default properties that cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans may be running the application on a different JVM than explorer, or maybe altering some of its properties (the -DXXX options).

Try setting `RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS` to `VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON`.

(more at: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS
)

Comment: I already tried setting `RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS` to `VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON` with no effect. How do i verify which JVM is being used and if Netbeans is altering its properties (the -DXXX options)?

Comment: This is the only relevant line in my `netbeans.conf`. Is this what you are refferring to? netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"

Comment: Right-click the project on the project tree, and choose "properties". Then look at the "run" part of the dialog. It should say which JVM netbeans uses for that project, and would allow you to set runtime options for the JVM.

Comment: I did not modify the defaults in the "properties" window. The VM options is empty and using JDK 1.6_43. The default JVM on my machine is 1.7_09. So you are right it because of different JVM versions. Any idea if this is a java bug?

Comment: Are you on a Mac? JVM 1.6 was Apple, JVM 1.7 is open source. So they had different graphic pipelines. Initially 1.7 didn't do retina displays at all. Try upgrading the JVM (or even use Java 8 runtime).

Comment: I am on a PC. Its a company Laptop and we HAVE to use what the IT want. There is no chance of installing anything other than what is already there. Here is the exact version. `java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)`

Comment: Also note that the `1.6.0_43` version is giving the desired results.

Comment: 1.6 is EOL-ed since Feb 2013 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html). That might help shake the IT guys a bit.
Try running it on a JVM whose version is > 1.7.0_40 (aka 7u40) and see what you get.